# How to classify nested xml tags in aws glue while capturing the attributes

Tags: xml, aws-glue

I have the following xml sample:

```
<ParentTag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="68067108" ClientID="1" DocumentCreationDate="2018-04-10T00:00:05" DocumentVersion="9" EventClassID="1987" STBLogCreationDate="2018-04-09T11:38:59" SampleID="496" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/opt/web/ams_proxy/webapps/ams_proxy/WEB-INF/amsXmlSchema_DTVPA_Version9.xsd">
    <Event EventTime="2018-04-09T11:41:02">
        <LiveViewEvent>
            <Channel channelObjectId="3062323">
                <Stream streamId="40" streamType="Video"/>
                <Stream streamId="41" streamType="Audio"/>
                <Stream streamId="65535" streamType="Data"/>
            </Channel>
        </LiveViewEvent>
    </Event>
</ParentTag>
```

I need the id in *ParentTag*, the *EventTime* and the *LiveViewEvent* data (channelObject, video, audio and data). I got to the point of getting the data in the LiveViewEvent (as a struct) and the *EventTime*, but it seems to skip the attributes in *ParentTag*.
Perhaps I should also mention that there are other types of events (than *LiveViewEvent* with different data but I don't need them.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to create a classifier  in the AWS Glue console with Row tag as "ParentTag" and then you will be able select the necessary data using struct and array data type.